# The package system is broken (18.04)

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've looked at countless threads here and have yet to find anything that has worked.

I'm currently taking some Linux classes so I will get better at this (hopefully) :).

Anyways, I've been trying to install a Nvidia driver with no luck. I have an error that says The package system is broken. It asks me to run `apt-get install -f`. So when I run this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I receive the following output:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-cfg1-390 libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-compute-390
  libnvidia-compute-390:i386 libnvidia-decode-390 libnvidia-decode-390:i386
  libnvidia-encode-390 libnvidia-encode-390:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-390
  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390 libnvidia-ifr1-390 libvdpau1
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libxnvctrl0
  mesa-vdpau-drivers nvidia-compute-utils-390 nvidia-dkms-390
  nvidia-kernel-common-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-390 pkg-config screen-resolution-extra
  vdpau-driver-all xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-390
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
(Reading database ... 168111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-390_390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-390_390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My mother's first instinct was correct: Clean up the mess you left behind after your previous failed attempts. Return your system to stock condition before starting your next attempt. The error message seems to indicate that previously-installed packages are incompatible with the new packages you wish to install.

Answer (score 0):

Start fresh. Install Ubuntu without even thinking about the video card. After the installation has completed, simply select **Additional Drivers** from the **Preferences** section.
The software will automagically probe for and confirm the NVIDIA hardware. You then only need to select it from the displayed menu and click **Apply**. Be patient, as it's a fairly large file to download and install. When it's done, reboot.
Afterwards, you'll find the **NVIDIA Settings** software in the **Administration** section of Ubuntu.
Have some tea.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give this a go. Let's hope for the best! :)

Comment: Did it work, @TravisW